# Functional Testing. Keep getting redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I've been trying to write some tests and I've been getting this error for everyone of them.

Expected response to be a redirect to [here](http://test.host/accounts/1/projects/1) but was a redirect to [here](http://test.host/login).

Here is my code for the test:

```
test "should go to projects show page" do
   get :show, id: @account, account_id: @project.account_id, employee_id: @consultant.id
   assert_redirected_to account_project_path
end
```

I am new to this and have looked at multiple online resources regarding this issue and have read the `Rails Guides` section on functional testing. Am 
I not setting the user in the session correctly? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well... yes. that will be my first guess. 
You are not setting the session for the user... and you probably have an authentication for the controller action you are trying to use.

Comment: Are you sure your action should be redirecting? The only reason a `show` action really should redirect is if user is not authorized (HTTP 401) or if the resource is not available (HTTP 404, 410). I'm guessing here that the real issue is not really your test - but rather the subject you are testing is not properly thought out.

Comment: What does `puts` tell you about the session/cookie?